# get properties using reflections for generic type object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am having a generic class in which I have a function to get properties of the generic object passed.It is as below.

```
public class ExportToCsv<T>        
        where T: class
{
    public ExportToCsv(List<T> obj)
    {
            this.Data = obj;       
    }

    public StringBuilder CreateRows()
   {
       IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
   }
}
```

It works fine and returns me properties if I pass the object by selecting from a object(class) like below

```
//GetLeadingRoutingRecords returns a class/object
var result = from obj in GetLeadRoutingRecords()
                    select new
                    {
                        LeadRoutingId = obj.LeadRoutingID,
                        Make = obj.Make
                     };
```

and pass that result as `result.ToList();`

but when I try to create my own anonymous object by creating a class for the properties like below it doesn't work
not returning any properties

Note : the below code is being called in a loop and it well functioning and being passed to the above function can see all values by debugging.

```
public CsvReport function return(){
    return new CsvReport
                {
                    ShopName = this.val,
                    TargetVehicleName = val
                 }.ToList();
}
```

class that I wrote for the above anonymous object is like below :

```
public class CsvReport
    {
        public string ShopName { get; set; }
        public string TargetVehicleName { get; set; }
    }
```

so in this case its not working, i am selecting first record and getting properties like below

```
this.Data.First().GetType().GetProperties();
```

I want to use the first pattern even here, which is `type(T).GetProperties`

So, any work around please........................

Comment: your "the below code" doesn't make much sense, which makes it a bit hard to comment - and your "anonymous object"... *isn't anonymous*: it is a `CsvReport`. Can you clarify? Ideally showing the code where you actually call `ExportToCsv`? Also: how is `this.Data` declared?

Comment: please provide smaller example, then it is easier to focus on the problem

Comment: How are you instantiating your `ExportToCsv<CsvReport>`?

Comment: Is what you posted the actual code used? I could imagine instead of `List<T>` you had something like `IEnumerable<T>` for the `ExportToCsv` constructor, then instantiated it with a base class instead of the concrete derived type. For example: `new ExportToCsv<object>(myCollectionOfCsvReports)`. That would cause it to look up properties on the base type `T` (`object` in this case which wouldn't yield anything usable), where as accessing the first item and calling `GetType()` on it would give you the `CsvReport` type which would yield your properties.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Reflection on `typeof(T)` works fine; here's a simpler example *based* on yours, but (importantly) *runnable*. It outputs:

```
ShopName
TargetVehicleName
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class CsvReport
{
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public string TargetVehicleName { get; set; }
}
class ExportToCsv<T>
{
    List<T> data;
    public ExportToCsv(List<T> obj)
    {
        data = obj;
    }
    public void WritePropNames()
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
    }

}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new List<CsvReport>();
        obj.Add(new CsvReport { ShopName = "Foo", TargetVehicleName = "Bar" });
        new ExportToCsv<CsvReport>(obj).WritePropNames();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same stuff u did but it didn't work for  me it is returning   "System.PropertyInfo[0]" instead of returning properties.

Comment: thanks I fixed the problem there some type inference missing in my code that's why it didn't work even i did same stuff as u did, I really appreciate your interest in helping me........